# Why isn't the inductive set _the_ set of natural numbers?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, foundations

ZFC's axiom of infinity states:

$$\exists x (\varnothing \in x \wedge \forall y \in x (y\cup \left \{y \right \} \in x)) $$

Isn't this set $ x $ really $\mathbb{N}$? It wouldn't be $\mathbb{N}$ if x would contain some set $z $ that is different from $\varnothing $, $ S (\varnothing)$, $ S (S (\varnothing)) $, etc. But we can't really prove that such a set $ z $ is an element of $ x $, or can we? I also know that this inductive set $ x $ is not unique, but that, in the light of my question, doesn't make any sense to me either. I feel like I'm missing a very peculiar technical point, and I don't know what it is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Another example from NFU (plus Infinity): the universal set $V$ contains $\emptyset$ and forall $x$ it contains $x\cup\{x\}$. But the universe is hardly just the natural numbers.

Comment: I'm no expert on ZF, but the axiom does *not* rule out the possibility of other "junk" being in $x$ in additional to elements of $N$. To obtain $N$, you must obtain the intersection of all sets like $x$.

Answer (score 3):

Another set which satisfies the axiom is $N''=\mathbb N \cup N'$ where $N'$ is the set containing $x_0 = \mathbb N$ (a set which is not in $\mathbb N$) and all the sets $x_{n+1} := x_n \cup \{ x_n\}$. If you define $n+1 := n \cup \{n\}$, $0 := \{\}$ and $\omega := \mathbb N$ you have
$$
N'' = \{0, 1, 2, \dots, \omega, \omega+1, \omega+2,\dots\}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Write 
$$\phi(x):\Leftrightarrow (\emptyset \in x\land \forall y\in x\,(y\cup\{y\}\in x)). $$
Then the Axiom of Infinity states 
$$\tag1 \exists I\,\phi(I).$$
From such a set $I$ you can *derive* (using the other axioms) the existence of
$$\tag2 \omega := \bigcap\{\,x\in\mathcal P(I):\phi(x)\,\}$$
and then *show* that this $\omega$ is what you want (and does not depend on the choice of $I$). However, trying to pack the minimality construction of $(2)$ into the axiom makes it look much more complicated than $(1)$ - and unnecessarily so, as we can prove just what we need.

Answer (score 0):

Axiom **INF** tells you that some set $x$ exists with property
$\phi\left(x\right)$ as defined in the answer of Hagen von Eitzen.

Applying axiom **SEP** you find that  $\omega:=\left\{ y\in x\mid\forall I\left[\phi\left(I\right)\Rightarrow y\in I\right]\right\} $
is a set.

Here $\omega=\left\{ 0,1,2,\dots\right\} $